# Unable to use value of useRef in value of input in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-ref, input-field

I have a dropdown based on which different fields gets rendered. Initially I have initialized selected option of dropdown in useEffect hook, corresponding fields gets rendered and are working fine.
But when different option or even same option is chosen from dropdown fields gets rendered but when I type something in it it gets cleared. I have used useRef to store values for field at index i in fields array.

```
export default function CreateEntry({ navigation }) {
      const { user, setLoading, setLoadingMsg } = useAuthContext();
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState("");
      const [categoriesList, setCategoriesList] = useState([]);
      const [primary, setPrimary] = useState("");
      const [primaryValue, setPrimaryValue] = useState("");
    
      const [fields, setFields] = useState([
        {
          name: "Email",
          value: "",
          type: "string",
          encrypt: false,
        },
        {
          name: "Password",
          value: "",
          type: "string",
          encrypt: true,
        },
      ]);
      const refInputs = useRef([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        firestore()
          .collection("categories")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((documentSnapshot) => {
            setCategoriesList(documentSnapshot.data().category);
            setSelectedCategory(documentSnapshot.data().category[0].name);
            setFields(documentSnapshot.data().category[0].fields);
            fields.map((field) => {
              refInputs.current.push("");
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }, []);
    
      const addInput = () => {
        refInputs.current.push("");
        setFields([
          ...fields,
          { name: "First", value: "", type: "string", encrypt: false },
        ]);
      };
      const removeInput = (i) => {
        refInputs.current[i] = "";
        setFields((fields) =>
          fields.map((field, index) => {
            if (index === i) {
              return null;
            }
            return field;
          })
        );
      };
      const setInputValue = (index, value) => {
        refInputs.current[index] = value;
      };
      const inputs = [];
    
      fields.forEach((field, i) => {
        if (field !== null) {
          inputs.push(
            <View
              key={i}
            >
              <TextInput
                onChangeText={(value) => setInputValue(i, value)}
                value={refInputs.current[i]}
              />
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => removeInput(i)}
              >
                <Ionicons name="close" style={[tw``]} size={22} color="#ddd" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }
      });
    
      const addEntry = () => {
        //
      };
    
      return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
          <Dropdown
            data={categoriesList}
            value={selectedCategory}
            onChange={(item) => {
              refInputs.current = [];
              setSelectedCategory(item.name);
              setFields(item.fields);
              item.fields.map((field) => {
                refInputs.current.push("");
              });
            }}
          />
      
          <Input
            onChangeText={setName}
            value={name}
            placeholder="Name"
          />
    
          {inputs}
          <Pressable onPress={addInput}>
            <Text}>+ Add a new input</Text>
          </Pressable>
    
          <MainButton onPress={addEntry}>Add</MainButton>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Try using useState instead useRef.